# What should be configured on Azure before publishing an ASP.NET Core web application?

Tags: azure, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application along with Entity Framework Core. Now I would like to host that application in Azure. I am new to Azure, so I don't know what needs to be configured on Azure before publishing the application to Azure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Sajeetharan said you can quickly publish your ASP.NET MVC Application in Azure easily from Visual Studio itself.

But you need to understand how this actually works within azure

**WebApps**

The service which is used to host every Web Application *(PaaS)* is called [**Azure Web 
Web**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-overview).

**App Service Plan**

An App Service plan is the container for your app. The App Service plan settings will determine the location, features, cost and compute resources associated with your app. *The Cost is based on the App Service plan and not the WebApps*

While publishing your web applications in Azure, is nothing but just deploying your code to WebApps.

**Update 1**

[image]

Happy Coding !

Comment: What if I want to use the free azure services, can I do that while publishing the application?

Comment: @AshishRathi, Of course, you can do that.Please see my **Update **1 in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to configure anything, if you already have an Azure subscribe just connect to your azure account via visual studio and create a new Web App to publish your code.

Read more here

[`Create an ASP.NET Core web app in Azure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-dotnet)

Comment: Then in this case which azure service plan will be selected? Azure provides the 12 months of free subscription for the user, so it is directly being used then?

Comment: You will be given with a selection box to select your subscription